# Read one side of the association

Tags: django, django-orm

Let's say we have two models in our Django app:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

Normally, for a many to many field I would make an intermediary table and just query that:

```
class ProjectMember(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
```

Is there a way to retrieve a queryset to list only the projects for a member?

I tried `ProjectMember.objects.filter(member=member).only('project')` but I still get the ProjectMember object list with only the `project` field populated.

I was wishing to retrieve a list of Project objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look "through" relations by querying with two consecutive underscores (`__`), so:

```
Project.objects.filter(projectmember__member=member)
```

Your `ProjectMember` model however acts as a junction table for a many-to-many relation between `Member` and `Project`. You can span a [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) on the `Project` model with:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    # …
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Member,
        related_name='projects',
        through='ProjectMember'
    )
```

Then you can filter with:

```
Project.objects.filter(members=member)
```

or even:

```
member.projects.all()
```